# Pass an Additional Parameter Into onChange Function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onchange, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to pass a spare boolean parameter into an `onChange` handler in ReactJS. The idea is, in a soccer match, the frontend will add match events as they happen (corners in this case). The idea is the boolean `homeOrAway` will represent whether the corner is awarded to the home or away team.

Here's the JSX and hooks:

```
  const [homeCorners, setHomeCorners] = useState(0);

        <Form>
          <Form.Group controlId="homeCorners"></Form.Group>
          <Form.Label>Home Corners</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="number"
            id="homeCornersInput"
            name="homeCorners"
            step="1"
            value={homeCorners}
            min="0"
            max="50"
            style={{
              width: "82.5px",
            }}
            onChange={(e) => adjustCorners(true)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form>
```

And here is the `adjustCorners` function. I've tried a curried function but it doesn't seem to work:

```
 function adjustCorners(homeOrAway) {
    let updatedMatchEvents = [...matchEvents];
    let cornerEvent = {
      isHome: homeOrAway,
      eventType: 1,
      playerId: 0,
      period: 1,
      minute: 0,
      second: 0,
    };

    return (event) => {
      if (homeOrAway === true) {
        if (event.target.value < homeCorners) {
          updatedMatchEvents.pop();
          setMatchEvents(updatedMatchEvents);
        } else {
          updatedMatchEvents.push(cornerEvent);
          setMatchEvents(updatedMatchEvents);
        }
      } else {
        if (event.target.value < awayCorners) {
          updatedMatchEvents.pop();
          setMatchEvents(updatedMatchEvents);
        } else {
          updatedMatchEvents.push(cornerEvent);
          setMatchEvents(updatedMatchEvents);
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

I've also tried just using a basic arrow function, but it doesn't seem to work either. I'm able to print to the console but the `Form` doesn't increment or decrement:

```
const adjustCorners = (homeOrAway, corners) => {
    let updatedMatchEvents = [...matchEvents];
    let cornerEvent = {
      isHome: homeOrAway,
      eventType: 1,
      playerId: 0,
      period: 1,
      minute: 0,
      second: 0,
    };

    if (homeOrAway === true) {
      if (corners < homeCorners) {
        updatedMatchEvents.pop();
        setMatchEvents(updatedMatchEvents);
      } else {
        updatedMatchEvents.push(cornerEvent);
        setMatchEvents(updatedMatchEvents);
      }
    } else {
      if (corners < awayCorners) {
        updatedMatchEvents.pop();
        setMatchEvents(updatedMatchEvents);
      } else {
        updatedMatchEvents.push(cornerEvent);
        setMatchEvents(updatedMatchEvents);
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your logic, `adjustCorners` return a function therefore you need to pass a value to it.

Moreover, you should pass the actual value and not the event object, due to how [Synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) works in React.

```
// Rewrite adjustCorners to use the value and not reference the event.
onChange={(e) => adjustCorners(true)(e.target.value)}

// BUG, DON'T DO IT, READ ABOUT SYNTHETIC EVENTS
onChange={(e) => adjustCorners(true)(e)} // !! BUG CAREFUL
```

Rewrite Example:

```
function adjustCorners(homeOrAway) {
  let updatedMatchEvents = [...matchEvents];
  let cornerEvent = {
    isHome: homeOrAway,
    eventType: 1,
    playerId: 0,
    period: 1,
    minute: 0,
    second: 0,
  };

  // Not event.target.value, pass the value
  return (value) => {
    if (homeOrAway === true) {
      if (value < homeCorners) {
        updatedMatchEvents.pop();
        setMatchEvents(updatedMatchEvents);
      } else {
        updatedMatchEvents.push(cornerEvent);
        setMatchEvents(updatedMatchEvents);
      }
    } else {
      if (value < awayCorners) {
        updatedMatchEvents.pop();
        setMatchEvents(updatedMatchEvents);
      } else {
        updatedMatchEvents.push(cornerEvent);
        setMatchEvents(updatedMatchEvents);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis. I'm not sure what you mean by rewriting adjustCorners to use the value though, can you provide an example?